# Integrating reCAPTCHA with existing PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I have a php script which uses the following line to submit a form :

```
<form action = "javascript:void(null);" onsubmit = "load_ajax();" name = "myform">
```

Now, to protect bots from misusing the form I want to implement reCAPTCHA as described here :

```
http://www.darksideofthecarton.com/2008/12/15/validating-recaptcha-with-jquery-and-ajax/
```

The reCAPTCHA logic is working fine displaying verification Success/Fail message but the form is not getting submitted. Here is the code I am using to implement reCAPTCHA :

```
<form action = "javascript:void(null);" onsubmit = "return validateCaptcha()" name = "myform">
```

Validation part which I am using to call my load_ajax() function (which denotes successful form submission) :

```
    function validateCaptcha()
{
    challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
    responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
    //alert(challengeField);
    //alert(responseField);
    //return false;
    var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.recaptcha.php",
    data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(html == "success")
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("Success. Submitting form.");
        return false;
        // Uncomment the following line in your application
        load_ajax();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("Image verification failed, Pls. enter the image verification code correctly.");
        Recaptcha.reload();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I am not a php/javascript expert so help is needed.

Thanks

Comment: I still can't believe people don't know how to implement jQuery unobtrusively. `<form action="return false;" ...` and the ilk is the bane of my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in this line inside validation routine (was returning false preventing form action routine) :

`$("#captchaStatus").html("Success. Submitting form."); 
return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not submitted because you don't do anything after validation.
Put an action in your form.action property and call it using jquery when validateCaptcha is true.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried the following : <form action = "javascript:load_ajax();" onsubmit = "return validateCaptcha()" name = "myform"> but it's not working, as I said am still learning javascript/php